# Trouble using a try-catch block

Tags: java, class, methods, try-catch

So I've got a simple class called `Date` with 3 data members and a separate class `Driver`; and I'm trying to error check the input with a try-catch block in my set method of class `Date`.

```
public void setDate(int month, int day, int year)
{
    try
    {
        dMonth = month;
        dDay = day;
        dYear = year;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException imeR)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong input type");
    }
}
```

But when I compile the class `Drive`...

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Date zeroDate = new Date ();

        System.out.println(zeroDate.getMonth());
        zeroDate.setDate(4,4,4);
        System.out.println(zeroDate.getMonth());
        zeroDate.setDate(4,4,"string");
    }
}
```

..., I get the following error:

```
Driver.java:14: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
        zeroDate.setDate(4,4,"ted");
```

Everything else works fine, and when I comment out the line...

```
zeroDate.setDate(4,4,"string");
```

..., I'm able to manipulate class Date just fine.

This is my first time trying a try-catch block. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: Java will not automatically convert a `String` to an `int`.  You have to use a method that will do that.  There are some methods in the `Integer` class that will do that for you.  The class documentation is at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).  Note also that the method that calls your parsing method is the one where you have to put the `catch`.  `setDate` just moves `int`'s around, without doing any parsing, so putting the `catch` block there is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't about the try-catch block. This is because you're passing in a string where an int is expected.
Because Java is statically typed, it will not let you do this at compile time.

Comment: Just to expand, `try...catch` statements will only catch runtime errors. Type-checking is done at compile time, as you say

Answer (score 0):

in your setDate method you get three int type , you can't pass any other data type to it..